# React native, expo. Looks like IF function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I have a function to create user, before I want to check basic logical things: if both passwords are entered, if they match, if all values are not empty strings:

```
handleSignUp = () => {

    if (this.state.name == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Please enter name" });
        else  if (this.state.email == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Please enter email" });
            else if (this.state.password == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Please enter password" });
                else  if (this.state.password2 == "") this.setState({ errorMessage: "Please repeat password" });
                    else if ( this.state.password != this.state.password2) this.setState({ errorMessage: "Passwords doesn't match" });
                        else { 
                            Fire.shared.createUser(this.state.user);
                        };
};
```

But I can create user with only first password, second absolutely empty...
What do I miss here?

Comment: It is unclear what `absolutely empty` means in your question. You might want to `console.log(this.state)` right before you run this code and include the output of that in your question.

Comment: absolutely empty means I never touch REPEAT PASSWORD text input field.

this.state values are decleared as empty strings. in example password = ""

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact value (for example by logging it as I said in my first comment), instead of telling us. Seeing the code and the corresponding data together makes it more likely that someone can see what's going wrong.

Comment: Basic debugging: just print out the value of the second password just below the 'createUser' line. Most probably it is not empty ("") but it's something else, like a " ".